# Upload audio recorded to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I'm trying to upload an audio that I recorded to a Firebase database. The recording is working fine, and the audio is also playing, I just need to upload it and also download it to the other users, so they can listen to it. The app itself is already sending text messages and they are working without any problem, the users can already chat among them.

This is were I record the audio (an audio recording session is already opened).

```
@IBAction func sendAudio(_ sender: Any) {
    //Check if there is an active AudioRecorder
    if audioRecorder == nil {
        numberOfRecords += 1
        let filename = getAudioFileURL()

        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

        //Start recording
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()

            audioButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        } catch {
            alertsAudio(title: "Error", message: "Error!")
        }
    } else {
        //Stop audio recording
        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil

        UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
        messageTableView.reloadData()



        audioButton.setTitle("Record", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

And this is how I get the file URL:

```
func getDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentDirectory
}

func getAudioFileURL() -> URL {
    return getDirectory().appendingPathComponent(".m4a")
}
```

Now I need to get this file URL and upload it to Firebase, and download it on the other users app.

I'm using this method to retrieve the text messages from the firebase:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("Worked!")
    if messageTextfield.text == "" {
        //o campo de mensagem está em branco
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!!!", message: "You can't send a message without text. Please type a message!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
        messageTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        messageTextfield.isEnabled = false
        sendButton.isEnabled = false

        let messagesDB = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")

//            if audioRecorder != nil{
//                message = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(numberOfRecords).m4a")
//            } else {
//                message = messageTextfield.text
//            }

        let messageDict = ["Sender": Auth.auth().currentUser?.email, "MessageBody": messageTextfield.text]

        messagesDB.childByAutoId().setValue(messageDict) {
            (error, reference) in

            if (error) != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                print("Message sent!")

                self.messageTextfield.isEnabled = true
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true

                self.messageTextfield.text = ""

            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Thanks for the attention guys!

Comment: Audio is just a series of bytes so one option is to convert those audio bytes into a Data object. Then encode the Data object with .base64EncodedStringWithOptions which will give you a string object that can be stored in Firebase. Just reverse the process when downloading it to the listeners app. That being said, there's a limit to node size in Firebase so you may want to explore Firebase Cloud Firestore or Storage instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, my upload method now it's like this:

```
@IBAction func sendAudio(_ sender: Any) {
    //Check if there is an active AudioRecorder
    if audioRecorder == nil {
        numberOfRecords += 1
        let filename = getAudioFileURL()

        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

        //Start recording
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record()

            audioButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        } catch {
            alertsAudio(title: "Recording error", message: "Error in the audio recording.")
        }
    } else {
        //Stopping the recording
        SVProgressHUD.show()

        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil

        UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")

        messageTableView.reloadData()
        audioButton.setTitle("Gravar", for: .normal)

        let fileUrl = getAudioFileURL()
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()


        metadata.contentType = "audio/mp4"
        let refStr = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)! + "|" + "\(NSUUID().uuidString)" + "|" + "recording.m4a"
        let pathStr = "Messages/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/\(refStr)"
        let uploadRef = storage.reference().child(pathStr)
        uploadRef.putFile(from: fileUrl, metadata: nil) { metadata,
            error in
            if error == nil {
                print("Successfully Uploaded Audio")
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                let downloadUrl = (metadata?.downloadURL())!
                print("URL: \(downloadUrl)")
                //completion(fileUrl)
                //let messagesDB = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")
                //let key = messagesDB.childByAutoId().key

                var messageInfoArray = refStr.components(separatedBy: "|")
                let messageDict = ["Sender": messageInfoArray[0], "MessageBody": "recording-audioRecorded", "AudioURL": "\(pathStr)", "AudioID": messageInfoArray[1], "IsAudio": "\(NSUUID().uuidString)-True"]

                let childUpdates = ["Mensagens/\(messageInfoArray[1])": messageDict]
                Database.database().reference().updateChildValues(childUpdates)

            }
            else {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                print("UploadError \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!!", message: "The following error ocurred \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }

    }
}
```